# Which plate needs to be cleansed when Tolandball moves to the ceiling of the room during the Prophecy dungeon 2nd encounter?

Tags: destiny-2

[image]

Normally Toland moves to a plate on one of the 4 walls clearly showing which plate needs to be cleansed.  In this instance, how do you know which plate to cleanse since he's in the center?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cleansing any plates will work, but if you want extra efficiency, here's what to do.
First of all, here's some insight about this encounter. The goal is to draw a circle on each side of the cube above you, 6 in total. Toland always just shows you a random side that doesn't have a circle on it.

When Toland is on top, look at the cube and find a side that doesn't have a circle on it. (In this case it's the one on the right.) Once you do, cleanse that side. If all the sides around the cube are already marked with a circle, just do any one you'd like, as the goal is to rotate the cube and to get to Toland's side.

Comment: Did not know about the circles in the middle... wonder how many times I've done that encounter and never saw it?